# WPF background colors

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to create some colors as my WPF background, but I have 2 issues with that:

1. When I resize windows, coloring being resized with it. I would like to have it static.
2. My colors are specific: They are not toned, they should look something like this:

[image: Colors]

But the problem is: When I create a gradient in WPF, color changes are kind of blurred.

I have tried to do it that way :

```
<Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#70116B" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#70116B" Offset="0.4" />
        <GradientStop Color="#BBD909" Offset="0.4" />
        <GradientStop Color="#BBD909" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#0093DD" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#0093DD" Offset="0.52" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.52" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

But like I said: it's not what I want

Comment: Isn't the colours supposed to blur together in a gradient brush? That looks nothing like gradient to me. :P [Gradient](http://img3.goodfon.su/original/2560x1600/e/96/tekstura-zalivka-blik.jpg)

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm trying to find a way to do that. It's not a perfect gradient, and I do not want to use image as background

Comment: Take a look here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-lineargradientbrush/

Comment: You need to make the offsets "pass/blend" with each other. Now they just end before another starts.

Comment: It's not answering my question. I know how gradient works, and that's why I put ' ' signs in title.
Your link also does not explain my problem with window resize

Comment: Yeah making the gradient sort of parallax, the window moves but the background does not? Maybe you need to create a large rectangle, fill it with the gradient colors and then show a portion of the rectangle as the background, tho i don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Why not just create a panel with filled rectangles as the bottom most visual element on your window? That way your elements are solid colours and you can fix the position as you would a label or other ui element

Comment: It's obvious that you don't really want a Gradient. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve isn't a gradient. But i would suggest you to use something like below:

```
  <Grid>  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.02*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.48*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#70116B"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#BBD909"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="#0093DD"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Background="#FFFFFF"/>
  </Grid>
```

Hope this helps!